# can't find references when building c# project in jenkins

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jenkins

After that I import a c# project from TFS to a Jenkins workspace, I try to compile him without installing Visual Studio, but i get the error bellow :

**CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'**

could someone give me a solution please ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Is this package a nuget-package? If so, did you add nuget restore step before build?

Comment: I've already done it

Answer (score 0):

You probably are missing an assembly-reference from the Office-SDK.

Check the project for references to any Microsoft.Office.*.dll, which will most likely be referenced from GAC.

Installing the appropiate Office-SDK on the Build-Agent might solve the issue.

Or, consider packaging the Office SDK as nuget-package. This would involve provisioning a private nuget-feed for consumption of these packages from your dev and your build-machine. Also, have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47654005/how-to-manage-third-party-asemblies-in-a-nuget-consistent-way), which covers this scenario in a broader way.